# Updates and enters in D3JS

Tags: d3.js

I have a 4 element data set and append those data to a div in my page(refer to the code below).

**Question 1)** The statically entered "p" of "I was already here" remained as is. However, I expected it to be updated in "1".

**Question 2)** When I reenter the data to the html, I expected a result as `1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4`. However, the output is `I was already here, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4`. Why does the first element(1) of the data array skipped when data is reentered?

Do you have any idea?

*Here is the body of my html file:*

```
<div><p>I was already here</p></div>
```

*This is my javascript code:*

```
var data = [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
var svg = d3.select("body");
var paragraphs = svg.select("div").selectAll("p").data(data);
// data added
paragraphs.enter().append("p").text( function(d) { return d; });
// new items are added.
paragraphs.enter().append("p").text( function(d) {return d;});
```

*Output is as follows:*

```
I was already here

2

3

4

2

3

4
```

You can find the jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/yaprak/3uaQ2/1/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `enter`, it only works for new elements. Since you have the one '

' there originally, nothing is happening. One way to manage this would be to do something like:

```
// this adds the paragraphs that are missing
paragraphs.enter().append('p');

// This will update all text
paragraphs.text(function(d) { return d; });
```

If you want it to give you `1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4`, you're going to run into some issues since the first element exists already, so you'd end up with `1 2 3 4 2 3 4`. You'll have to make your data set bigger, which can be done easily using `concat` like so:

```
var paragraphs = svg.select("div").selectAll("p").data(data.concat(data));
```

[Here's an updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3uaQ2/2/)

---

You can think of it kind of like this:

- Your `selectAll` is going to get all existing ones.
- `enter` will do stuff to anything that is new, ie everything greater than the first `<p>`
- calling `text` on `paragraphs` after you've done the `enter` is an updating all elements

When you called `enter` again, it was again only going through the missing ones, which is why you were only getting 2 - 4.

I hope that helps.

Comment: this might be helpful http://blog.sathomas.me/post/web-based-visualization-part-1-the-d3.js-key-concept